# how to create a regex to validate id with 3 dots or dashes

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to allow users to enter id like the following format only

```
1

1.1 or 1-1

1.1.1 or 1-1-1

1.1.1.1 or 1-1-1-1
```

i wrote the following regex.

```
/^(\d+(?:-\d+)*$)|(^\d+(?:\.\d+)*$)/
```

it gives me the above output. but the problem is it allows unlimited matches. But i want maximum of 4 numbers (only 4)

`1.23.4.55` or `1-23-4-55`  correct

but `1.1.1.1.1` or `1-1-1-1-1` or `21.34.55.5.5.5.5` should be wrong

but my regex take this also as correct

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use

```
^\d+([.-]\d+){0,3}$
```

If you don't want to mix separators, use

```
^\d+((-\d+){0,3}|(\.\d+){0,3})$
```

Comment: I'd use non-capturing groups and there is no need to escape the dot inside a character class.

Comment: @stribizhev There may be a small slowdown related to the capturing groups in some engines (not all, when just *testing* instead of *matching*) but in most cases I don't feel like the gain is worth the reduction in readability.